# Is it possible to call SOAP web services with Rebol 3 cURL binding?

Tags: curl, exec, rebol, rebol3

I have some Rebol 2 code calling a SOAP web service using the [shell interface function](http://rebol.com/docs/shell.html) CALL:

```
soap-request: rejoin [{<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>}

    soap-body ;-- Payload string of the request

    {</SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>}
]

soap-response: copy {}

call/wait/input/output rejoin [
    curl-directory {\curl -H }
    {"SOAPAction: " -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d @- <URL web service>}
] soap-request soap-response
```

It doesn't seem the CALL function in Rebol 3 Alpha is able to do this yet.

But is it possible to achieve equivalent behavior with [Esper Consultancy's Rebol 3 cURL binding](http://rebol.esperconsultancy.nl/extensions/cURL/)?  What would that code look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply & edit, HostileFork. Actually, I don't see any way to perform a POST request in the documentation of [Esper Consultancy's Rebol3's cURL binding](http://rebol.esperconsultancy.nl/extensions/cURL/). I must add that I want to use cURL because I'm behind a proxy server, and proxy is not yet supported in REBOL3 HTTP, as far as I know. And I want to use REBOL3 to make a demo of this new GUI : new R3 GUI + networking using cURL (with HTTPS / proxy support).

Comment: @dreamyToto Did you try with Rebol 3's plain HTTP? The above curl invocation does not explicitly specify any proxy settings (but they may be implicitly picked up from environment variables or other system-wide configuration) -- so maybe you have a transparent proxy that would work with Rebol 3's regular HTTP protocol just as well?

Comment: @dreamyToto Please feel free to join us in the [Rebol and Red](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) chat room here... you have the 20 point minimum needed to chat now... we can talk more about what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I will create another question on using plain HTTP POST with REBOL3. I've not seen a lot of documentation on that